# convert string into integer when number over than 2147483647

Tags: php

```
$_GET[id];

$id=(int)$_GET['id'];

mysql store - int
```

I have a question about convert string into integer.

(Convert post id to make sure user don't send string)

and mysql store type - int

---

I notice if the id is bigger than 2147483647, the number become crazy.

what if website posts are more than 2147483647?

is any way to convert it into bigint? or I shouldn't convert string into int?

Do I have change mysql store type to - bigint?

Comment: _the number become crazy._ what do you mean by?

Comment: I don't know of any site with 2 billion posts in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signed `INT` in MySql [can only go up to 2^31](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html), so yes -- you will have to convert the column to `BIGINT`.

Apart from that you must also deal with PHP's restrictions. An integer in PHP cannot be greater than `PHP_INT_MAX` (the exact value depends on the environment), so numbers larger than that have to be processed in string or floating point form if you stick to the primitives. Keeping the value as a string should be OK since it's an id, and you don't do math with ids.